# Alto de Celda Fijo

Tags: html, html5

Tengo un elemento Table en alguna celdas a veces muestro un texto muy grande por lo cual la celda crece en Alto, tenia pensado ponerle un alto fijo y mostrar un tooltip para poder ver todo el contenido de la celda. he intentado con style="table-layout:fixed", también he puesto style="height:5px;" para cada , pero aun no logro el efecto deseado. adjunto captura.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas espero esto te ayude

Los `td` no pueden ser objetos de bloque osea que algunas propiedades no les afecta pero para solucionar eso hay que poner la información dentro de un contenedor en este caso un `p` y a el las propiedades que desees

```css
table td p{
 height: 50px;
 overflow:auto;
 background: rgb(237, 237, 237);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>texto</th>
    <th>texto2</th>
    <th>texto3</th>
    <th>texto4</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
    </td>
    <td>
    hola mundo
    </td>
    <td>
    hola mundo
    </td>
    <td>
    hola mundo
    </td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
    </td>
    <td>
    hola mundo
    </td>
    <td>
    hola mundo
    </td>
    <td>
    hola mundo
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias, problema resuelto.

Comment: Genial que bueno ayudarte amigo